# Swift4 - Xcode 9 PCH error

Tags: swift, xcode9, pch

This project works well all the time until I install a framework. Once the framework seems hard to handle, I uninstall it. Then, xcode 9 read PCH error.

I perform this project with Swift, and I know little about OC. How this error happens suddenly?

The error cannot be cleaned~~ I do not know why and how to handle this

[image]

UPDATE:

I solved this by myself. Though simple and crude, it finally worked:

1. Clean abandoned tissues in -> project-> Link -> other Link flags
2. Clean abandoned tissues in -> target -> Built settings -> search path ->Header search path.
3. Update -> target -> Built settings -> search path ->Framework search path, discard unavailable issue.
4. Delete file name started with Pod, except Podfile, and re-execute pod install.

I still do not know which way works, but it finally worked. Feel so weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift + alt + command ⌘ + K

Clean the derived data, build again.

Comment: I updated the question issue. Thanks all the same. Maybe I could try your thing next time, seems more convenient.